# Send Data from a azure webapp to 2 azure application insights in two different azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Hello I hope you can help me.

I have a azure webapp that is basically an api programmed in dotnet core, this is connected to an azure application insights, where we monitor the api, the problem I have is that only one person on the team has access to these two resources(webapp and app insights), basically the permission for all rest of the team is a bureaucratic management that does not end resolving.

I need the data stored in the application insights to be replicated in another insights application in a new azure subscription that we already created where all team members have access.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This question doesn't need a technical answer. You need to work out the process in your org.

Comment: Are you using C# + Net core or other technologies ?